# Corda - CorDapp JAR Signing Causes Build Exception

Tags: kotlin, gradle, corda

I'm following [these instructions](https://blog.b9lab.com/why-you-need-to-sign-your-cordapps-and-how-to-do-it-464101e5ec71) to sign my CorDapp, but it's causing a build failure. Here's what I've done so far:

1. Created the key store in the following directory

```
~/.gradle/keystore/jarsign.pkcs12
```

2. Added the following lines to `gradle.properties`

```
jar.sign.keystore=~/.gradle/keystore/jarsign.pkcs12
jar.sign.password=NotMyRealPassword
```

3. Added this to my CorDapp gradle config (variables)

```
ext {
    cordapp_signing_enabled = true
    cordapp_signing_alias = 'cordapp-signer'
    cordapp_signing_storetype = 'PKCS12'
    cordapp_signing_keystore = getProperty('jar.sign.keystore')
    cordapp_signing_password = getProperty('jar.sign.password')
}
```

4. Added this to my CorDapp gradle config (cordapp signing)

```
signing {
    enabled = cordapp_signing_enabled
    options {
        keystore cordapp_signing_keystore
        alias cordapp_signing_alias
        storepass cordapp_signing_password
        keypass cordapp_signing_password
        storetype cordapp_signing_storetype
    }
}
```

When I attempt to build (from either IntelliJ or the terminal), I get the following error

> Exception while signing contract-0.1.jar, ensure the 'cordapp.signing.options' entry contains correct keyStore configuration, or disable signing by 'cordapp.signing.enabled false'. Run with --info or --debug option and search for 'ant:signjar' in log output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be due to the key-store path being relative

This didn't work...

```
jar.sign.keystore=~/.gradle/keystore/jarsign.pkcs12
```

...but this did...

```
jar.sign.keystore=/Users/me/.gradle/keystore/jarsign.pkcs12
```